# Burp Suite doesn't intercept HTTPS calls from Advanced Rest Client

Tags: rest, https, proxy, sinatra, burp

I'm using [burp suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to intercept the calls that I do with the plugin Advanced Rest Client and with a sinatra application that is called by the Advanced Rest Client.

I've set it as proxy of my whole system, but still it intercepts only the calls by Chrome :(

Any idea?

Comment: Does the Sinatra app serve you a page, in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that my requests were using OAuth and SSL, so they are not filtered by Burp Suite.